# Angular - Running repeated tasks in background tabs?

Tags: javascript, angular, websocket

I have an Angular webapp that opens a websocket to my server, and the server sends a new data packet to the app every second. When the websocket in the app receives the message, I do some minor processing and then show the data to the user in a plot.

When I change tabs, it appears that my processing continues to happen once a second, until about 10 minutes have passed while the tab is in the background. Then, my app locks up. If I leave it in the foreground, it eventually "catches back up" and runs my processing routine many times per second - like the function calls are queued up.

The behavior seems to be consistent with both Chrome and Safari on both Linux and Mac.

Does anyone know what is going on here? Why would the background processing suddenly change after a certain period of time?

Answer (score 0):

This is a recent change, aiming to reduce battery consumption. Sadly there is no real opt-out, if your app is running in the background it will get throttled. More details on the [article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/background_tabs#opt-outs) explaining this in details on Google developers portal.

> Shipping in Chrome 57, budget-based timer throttling is a further extension of the timer alignment mechanism, placing an additional limit on background timer CPU usage. It operates as follows:
>
> - Each background tab has a time budget (in seconds) for running timers in the background.
> - A page is subjected to time budget limitations after 10 seconds in the background.
> - A timer task is allowed to run only when the time budget is non-negative.
> - After a timer has executed, its run time is subtracted from the budget.
>     The budget continuously regenerates with time (currently set to a rate of 0.01 seconds per second). Note that this budget regeneration rate can be tweaked as Chrome collects more data about throttling behavior.
>
> There are a number of automatic exemptions from this throttling:
>
> - Applications playing audio are considered foreground and aren’t throttled.
> - Applications with real-time connections (WebSockets and WebRTC), to avoid closing these connections by timeout. The run-timers-once-a-second rule is still applied in these cases.

The particular rule you are affected by is:

> Applications with real-time connections (WebSockets and WebRTC), to avoid closing these connections by timeout. The run-timers-once-a-second rule is still applied in these cases.

Comment: Hmm, so I don't understand why my application would be having issues here. If having an active websocket (which I do) is an exemption, shouldn't my functions work just fine?

Comment: The wording is not the best here, but I think your web socket events fire only once per second same as with timers.